# How can the server application `gollum` write data to the disk or commit it to a git repository?

Tags: browser, git, wiki

This question is probably related to either, a lack of understanding of how server apps accessed via a webbrowser on a localhost http address function, a wrong setup of my system, or to wrong expectations from me. Being unable to determine this, I hope comments at least will guide me to improving the post.

I have a `git` repository with a single markdown file, and a local copy of it in `$HOME/wiki`.

I have installed `gollum` with `sudo gem install gollum`

I have changed dir to `$HOME/wiki` and started gollum with `gollum --host localhost`

Browsing to `http://localhost:4567`, I do have an interface that allows me to preview and to edit the existing page, and to create new ones. However, even after pressing `Save` in this interface, there is no change in the `$HOME/wiki` existing file and no new file created. I do not find either in the interface a way to commit the changes done there with a `git` instance.

I expected that I would have either of these methods to propagate my changes. Is it a wrong expectation, does it work another way? Or did I miss a necessary step in the installation of `gollum`? [This page](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2021/01/07/gollum-markdown-wiki/) has a wealth of information, but is too much for me and I'd need guidance to identify the minimum settings required.

Comment: It’s important to note that this is _not_ in-browser. It’s a server application like any other. // Apparently, Gollum is using Git. So have you properly checked the state of the repository that Gollum saves to?

Comment: @DanielB thanks for correcting me,. Yes, Gollum is supposed to use git, but I don't understand how. The repository is unchanged, at any rate.